# Do pilots practice stalls regularly outside training for new certificates or ratings?

Tags: flight-training, stall

I know that stall practice in real aircraft is part of PPL training, and that airline pilots training for type ratings practice stalls in simulators. After obtaining a certificate/type rating, do pilots continue to practice stalls regularly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pilots operating under U.S. Federal Aviation Regulations do practice/train in "stalls" as noted below.

In the U.S., stall recognition, stalls, and stall recovery should be part of the Flight Review required under [14 CFR Part 61.56](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.56).  FAA Advisory Circular [AC 61-98D,](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-98D.pdf) (guidance for Flight Reviews), paragraph 4.3.5.4 states:

> Regardless of the pilot's experience, the flight instructor should review at least those maneuvers considered critical to safe flight, such as:
>
> - Takeoffs;
> - Stabilized approaches to landings;
> - Slow flight;
> - **Stall recognition, stalls, and stall recovery;**
> - Spin recognition and avoidance;
> - Recovery from unusual attitudes; and
> - Operating the aircraft by sole reference to instruments under actual or simulated conditions.

*(emphasis is mine)*

For U.S. Air Carrier operations [14 CFR Part 121.423(c)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-G/part-121/subpart-N#p-121.423(c)) states:

> (c) Extended envelope training must include instructor-guided hands on experience of **recovery from full stall and stick pusher activation,** if equipped.

*(emphasis is mine)*

The above Part 121 training is to be completed in a Level C or higher full flight simulator.

Comment: Well, your first source only says they should be part of the review, that doesn't mean that pilots actually practice them (as much as they should). When reading articles by e.g. Steve Krog and other regular columnists in Sport Aviation, I do get the impression that most PPL holders in the US do not practice stalls enough.

Comment: @Raketenolli I don't disagree with your point. Keep in mind, however,  that during the review if the CFI determines that compentcy in a particular maneuver (e.g., stalls) is weak, administering training during the review is appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

That entirely depends on the pilot. I practice stalls, steep turns and practiced forced landings on a regular basis, partly to keep my skills up and partly because I find it fun. Some pilots never do these things except when they have to in recurrent training and checkrides. For private pilots there's no requirement to practice these regularly.

Answer (score 2):

Ancedotally, glider pilots often practise stalls (as well as things like steep thermalling turns) on flights where there is no chance of lift and you may as well do something useful/fun with your time in the air.